# Static header on a webpage without zoom/scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
+--------screen-----------------------+
|       ______________________      |*|
|       |___static_header____|      |*|
|       |                    |      |*|
|       |      content       |      |*|
|       |     scrollable     |      |*|
|       |      zoomable      |      |*|
|       |                    |      |*|
|       |                    |      |*|
+-------------------------------------+
```

The content is variable height, and I would like it to be zoomable and scrollable. The header should be static with fixed size ignoring the client's zoom level. I'm not sure I have seen this done before. My current code below still isn't right for scrolling: the scrollbar goes all the way up to the header and I would like it to stop at the edges of content both for zooming and for scrolling. Is this doable without using an iframe for the content section? It doesn't need to be CSS-only

```css
body {
    padding: 0;  
}
.wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
.static {     
    width:1000px;
    z-index:2;
    height:100px;
    position: fixed;   
}
.header {
    background-color: silver;
    height:100px;
}
.content {
    background-color: orange;
    width:800px;
    height:500px;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="static">
        <div class="header">
            Header
        </div>   
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Upon closer inspection, Miro/Figma both use canvas to do this. I'm not sure if this means it's not doable without it or not

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a `height` on the parent, in this case the `body` for `overflow: hidden;` to work as expected. Then you can set the heights on the other elements, just ensure they don't exceed the `100%` so there is no `body` `overflow`.  See the changes below.

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
}

.static {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: sticky;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
  background-color: silver;
  height: 100px;
}

.content {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 80%;
  height: 95%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.content-wrapper {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="static">
    <div class="header">
      Header
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">scroll this content only
    <div class="content-wrapper"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this because it fixes the scrollbar issue however the header is still affected by the zoom level but I need to keep it at its original size

Comment: @charmeleon See edits, does that help?

Comment: I don't see a difference from the previous version. For reference, it seems Figma manages to do this (though I don't know how yet) where they have a floating bar at the top while you can zoom in on the "viewport"